# HTTP request isn't working on Chrome, yet works on all other browsers

Tags: google-chrome

I am getting "**net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE**" in chrome console while trying to call this: http://live.mp3quran.net:9988/;stream.nsv&type=mp3&autostart=true and anyting from live.mp3quran.net. Even though it works on all other browsers!

I originally used to call it by code by new audio() (JavaScript) with no issues for two months or more.